# IIS authentication challenge even with Anony turned on.. why?

Tags: iis, windows-server-2003

I have a windows 2003 server (WEb edition) which has .net 3.5 sp1 installed on it.

I've got a half dozen websites, all of which are challenging me for a username and password. If I supply a domain username, I get in fine...

However, I have the websites set to Allow anony access. The website files/folders all have the appropriate IUSR security setup and I can't get the challenge to go away. I've even gone as far as giving EVERYONE full control... still no dice.

Is there somewhere else I can check to get past this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these are .net websites you need to make sure that the "Network Service" user account has the proper permissions on the website folders/files.

Also, make sure that "Network Service" has full control over the "Temporary Aspnet Files" directory located here: C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. Just because Anonymous access is enabled doesn't mean there aren't users with more privileges so it has to check if any credentials are supplied.

Comment: The downvote was unnecessary. It's unclear if he's saying a log in window is popping up or a challenge packet is coming through. Jimmie assumed the former, I assumed the later. :P